# Popups fail in JQueryMobile 1.3.2 after update chrome version 43.0.2357.65 m

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

Has the latest chrome version "43.0.2357.65 m" broken JQueryMobile 1.3.2 for anyone else? When I click a popup now it goes to the top of the page and the scroll bar dissapears. It was fine in previous version.

The problem is affecting my applicaiton but is reproduceable on the JQueryMobile demo pages:

1. Using Chrome 43.0.2357.65 m go to http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/
2. Click on popup
3. On the popup page click on "Sign in" button halfway down the page.
4. It will go to the top of the page and the scrollbar will have disappeared.

Note this doesn't happen every time - if you try it again it might work, but if you start the steps from a fresh tab it does appear to happen consistently.

I've raised an issue with Chrome but just wondering if anyone knows what's happening and if there's a workaround I can implement.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also seeing issues in an old app with 1.2.0, specifically around page transitions.

Comment: I'm also seeing page transition issues in an old app with 1.2.x - no errors in the console but the whole page goes white after the transition. We removed it as a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The popup seems to be odd it's hard to replicate - 
Going to the exact link below and then clicking on the said "sign in" button seems to guarantee the behaviour.
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/popup/#&ui-state=dialog

I believe the solution below may be related it fixes other fun issues with the slide transition. (only limited test with popup) but looks promising

**Overriding the offending function with code snippet below.**
You have to call this before you load jquerymobile js

```js
// Override of $.fn.animationComplete muse be called before initialise jquery mobile js
   $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
     $.fn.animationComplete = function(callback) {
       if ($.support.cssTransitions) {
         var superfy= "WebKitTransitionEvent" in window ? "webkitAnimationEnd" : "animationend";
         return $(this).one(superfy, callback);
       } else {

         setTimeout(callback, 0);
         return $(this);
       }
     };

   })
```

**Background:**
jqueryMobile 1.3.2 implements the jquery one() event handler attachment somewhat incorrectly.

.one() - "Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed **at most once per element per event type.**" : http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ : essentially event fires and then is removed.

However calling both **("webkitAnimationEnd and animationend")** using **one()**  would potentially mean that only 1 (depending on browser) of the two handlers is ever fired leaving the other too linger and potentially cause memory leaks.

Chrome43 handles both webkitAniationEnd and animationend - however only one at any given time. This leaves the other to linger and fire off the next time animation on the element occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for me, it seems to work if you use the jQueryMobile API.

```
$('selector').popup('open');
```

instead of relying on the jQueryMobile markup

My Chrome Version is "43.0.2357.81 m" and I am experiencing this too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunatley my app uses the API already to open and close the popup, and it's seeing the problem.