# jquery mobile 1.2.0 blank screen in chrome Version 43.0.2357.81

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile

jquery mobile 1.2.0 version blank screen while slide in chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m. in other browsers ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already has an answer.

Check out my answer from here
[Animation end webkitend bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30439683/2604323)

You're better off moving to the latest version.

**edit**

To fix - just add somewhere before loading jquerymobile.js -

```
// Override of $.fn.animationComplete must be called before initialise jquery mobile js
   $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
     $.fn.animationComplete = function(callback) {
       if ($.support.cssTransitions) {
         var superfy= "WebKitTransitionEvent" in window ? "webkitAnimationEnd" : "animationend";
         return $(this).one(superfy, callback);
       } else {

         setTimeout(callback, 0);
         return $(this);
       }
     };

   })
```

Comment: am asking for slide transition

Comment: Yes similar same issue. First slide/popup in or out is OK second one will cause a blank screen or general weirdness on the new chrome, as both WebKit animationend  and animationend is called.

Comment: that script or i want add the function one()

Comment: just insert that script before you call jquerymobile,js... the one() is just explanation....