# jqm data-rel=back showing blank page

Tags: jquery-mobile, back, rel, no-data

In jQuery Mobile, though the `data-rel="back"` attribute is correctly returning me back to the previous page URL, but its not showing any content on that previous page.

I need the prev page content to be stored in history and to be retrieved once I click on the button having `data-rel="back"` attribute.

Even the browser back button is working in the exact same manner on being navigated back.

I'm stuck with this. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your code and possibly create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back">back</a>

Answer (score 2):

Try this out (by Superfy) -

[jquery mobile 1.2.0 blank screen in chrome Version 43.0.2357.81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643770/jquery-mobile-1-2-0-blank-screen-in-chrome-version-43-0-2357-81)

It worked for me. What version of Chrome are you using? Have you tried upgrading your jquery version to 1.4? 1.4 does not have slide transition related issues.