# jQuery mobile 1.3.2 slide transition broken in Chrome 43

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, transition, slide

In Chrome 43, the slide page transition of jQuery mobile 1.3.2 seems to be broken. It used to work in older versions of Chrome.

Steps to reproduce:
Go to 
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/transitions/
Click on the "page" button of the "slide" transition.
On the new page click on "Take me back".
After the transition, the old page will disappear.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Same here ... as a quick fix, I've switched to another transition.
In newer jqm versions everything works fine.

Comment: Check out answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439683/popups-fail-in-jquerymobile-1-3-2-after-update-chrome-version-43-0-2357-65-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to upgrade to latest jQuery Mobile version (> 1.4 ). Also there is an issue with **animationComplete** function in jQuery Mobile 1.3.2