# Scroll issue and random redirect in Phonegap + Jquery mobile in IOS 9

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, ios9

I have a Phonegap app with Jquery mobile in the AppStore.

I recently updated my phone to IOS 9 and the scroll stop worked. Im also having problem with the navigation inside the app. The app random redirect the user to the previous page when the user press a link or sometimes when the app makes ajax calls.

I know that IOS 9 have a lots of bugs already but i really need to fix this problem, because the app is actually in production and the users are reporting the same problem.

I found some problems related to Safari in IOS 9 but i had no luck with the scroll problem.

In IOS 8 and below the app work fine.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set style="overflow: auto" for data-role="page" for iOS 9 alone. the scroll will be sticky some times but it will resolve the showstopper status temporarily.

Comment: Siva, Thank you very much for the hot fix. It works. I was struggling with this problem for 5 days. You man deserve a medal.

Comment: Infact i am using JQm(1.4.0) in my other project with i do not see any issue with scrolling. It is a bug in v1.3.0 JQM with iOS9

Comment: You are right. Now i'm using JQM (1.4.5) and i don't have the issues.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research and a lot of experiments i decided to migrate my app to the latest version of jquery mobile (1.4.5) and that solved the scroll and navigation issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue on my application as well, my app is running JQM 1.3.2. I tried Siva Reddy solution, it is work but no perfect - scrolling is really sticky sometimes. And finally, I found a better solution in here

[Popups fail in JQueryMobile 1.3.2 after update chrome version 43.0.2357.65 m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439683/popups-fail-in-jquerymobile-1-3-2-after-update-chrome-version-43-0-2357-65-m)

Actually the problem causing the page not scrolling is because older JQM version handle "webkitAnimationEnd" event incorrectly. So when page transition is done, the webkitAnimationEnd/animationend is not being cleared up. This bug happens both on Android and iOS. Further discussion can be found on this link
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479502